# Can I inherit "set +h" to a sub process?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I seem unable to inherit the effect of `set +h` to a called shell script:

Here is a shell script (`./call`).

```
#!/bin/bash

set +h
export SHELLOPTS

./called
```

And here is the contents of `./called`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo \$-=$-
echo SHELLOPTS=$SHELLOPTS
```

When I execute `./call`, the following is printed:

```
$-=hB
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
```

I thought that shell options are inherited when I export `SHELLOPTS`. This is apparently not the case.

Is there a way to inherit the effect of `set +h` to a called shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables):

> The options appearing in SHELLOPTS are those reported as ‘on’ by ‘set
>   -o’.  If this variable is in the environment when Bash starts up, each 
>   shell option in the list will be enabled before reading any startup
>   files.

It follows that options *turned off* do not show up in `SHELLOPTS`, and so has no effect on whether the new shell enables or disables them.

You could try either of:

- run the script with `bash +h ./called`, or
- put `set +h` in a file, set `BASH_ENV` to the path of that file and `export` it, thought this will affect *all* instances of bash started down the line unless one of those unsets or unexports it.